# How to insert a photo on left side of the collection section?? [Shopify]

Tags: html, css, grid, shopify

Hello someone can guide me how to use grid in default section for debut theme??
I want to edit the featured collection to add a image on the left and collection on the right

Demo: https://strokes-test.myshopify.com/

similar with this one
[image]

currently the default for the Debut theme is this one

[image]

featured-collection.liquid

```
  {% if section.settings.title != blank %}
    <div class="section-header text-center">
      <h2>{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  {%- assign collection = collections[section.settings.collection] -%}

  {% case section.settings.grid %}
    {% when 2 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
    {% when 3 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 345 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-third' -%}
    {% when 4 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 250 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
    {% when 5 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth' -%}
  {% endcase %}

  {%- assign product_limit = section.settings.grid | times: section.settings.rows -%}

  <ul class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items">
    {% for product in collection.products limit: product_limit %}
      <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
        {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
      </li>
    {% else %}

      {% for i in (1..product_limit) %}
        <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
          <div class="grid-view-item product-card">
            <a class="grid-view-item__link grid-view-item__image-container full-width-link" href="#">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="grid-view-item__image-wrapper">
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
            <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title" aria-hidden="true">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
            {% include 'product-price' %}
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  {% if section.settings.show_view_all %}
    <hr class="hr--invisible" aria-hidden="true" />
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="{{ collection.url }}" class="btn" aria-label="{{ 'collections.general.view_all_label' | t: collection_name: collection.title }}">
        {{ 'collections.general.view_all' | t }}
      </a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

</div>



{% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "da": "Udvalgt kollektion",
    "de": "Vorgestellte Kategorie",
    "en": "Category collection",
    "es": "Colección destacada",
    "fi": "Esittelyssä oleva kokoelma",
    "fr": "Collection en vedette",
    "hi": "फ़ीचर्ड कलेक्शन",
    "it": "Collezione in evidenza",
    "ja": "特集コレクション",
    "ko": "추천 컬렉션",
    "nb": "Utvalgt samling",
    "nl": "Uitgelichte collectie",
    "pt-BR": "Coleção em destaque",
    "pt-PT": "Coleção em destaque",
    "sv": "Utvald kollektion",
    "th": "คอลเลกชันแนะนำ",
    "zh-CN": "特色产品系列",
    "zh-TW": "精選商品系列"
  },
  "class": "index-section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": {
        "da": "Overskrift",
        "de": "Titel",
        "en": "Heading",
        "es": "Título",
        "fi": "Otsake",
        "fr": "En-tête",
        "hi": "शीर्षक",
        "it": "Heading",
        "ja": "見出し",
        "ko": "제목",
        "nb": "Overskrift",
        "nl": "Kop",
        "pt-BR": "Título",
        "pt-PT": "Título",
        "sv": "Rubrik",
        "th": "ส่วนหัว",
        "zh-CN": "标题",
        "zh-TW": "標題"
      },
      "default": {
        "da": "Udvalgt kollektion",
        "de": "Vorgestellte Kategorie",
        "en": "Category collection",
        "es": "Colección destacada",
        "fi": "Esittelyssä oleva kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection en vedette",
        "hi": "फ़ीचर्ड कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione in evidenza",
        "ja": "特集コレクション",
        "ko": "추천 컬렉션",
        "nb": "Fremhevet samling",
        "nl": "Uitgelichte collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção em destaque",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção em destaque",
        "sv": "Utvald kollektion",
        "th": "คอลเลกชันแนะนำ",
        "zh-CN": "特色产品系列",
        "zh-TW": "精選商品系列"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "collection",
      "type": "collection",
      "label": {
        "da": "Kollektion",
        "de": "Kategorie",
        "en": "Collection",
        "es": "Colección",
        "fi": "Kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection",
        "hi": "कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione",
        "ja": "コレクション",
        "ko": "컬렉션",
        "nb": "Samling",
        "nl": "Collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção",
        "sv": "Produktserie",
        "th": "คอลเลกชัน",
        "zh-CN": "收藏",
        "zh-TW": "商品系列"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "grid",
      "label": {
        "da": "Produkter pr. række",
        "de": "Produkte per Reihe",
        "en": "Products per row",
        "es": "Productos por fila",
        "fi": "Tuotteita per rivi",
        "fr": "Produits par rangée",
        "hi": "प्रति पंक्ति उत्पाद",
        "it": "Prodotti per riga",
        "ja": "行あたりの商品数",
        "ko": "열 별 제품",
        "nb": "Produkter per rad",
        "nl": "Producten per rij",
        "pt-BR": "Produtos por linha",
        "pt-PT": "Produtos por linha",
        "sv": "Produkter per rad",
        "th": "สินค้าต่อแถว",
        "zh-CN": "每行产品数",
        "zh-TW": "每列產品數"
      },
      "min": 2,
      "max": 5,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "rows",
      "label": {
        "da": "Rækker",
        "de": "Reihen",
        "en": "Rows",
        "es": "Filas",
        "fi": "Rivit",
        "fr": "Rangées",
        "hi": "पंक्ति",
        "it": "Righe",
        "ja": "行",
        "ko": "열",
        "nb": "Rader",
        "nl": "Rijen",
        "pt-BR": "Linhas",
        "pt-PT": "Linhas",
        "sv": "Rader",
        "th": "แถว",
        "zh-CN": "行数",
        "zh-TW": "列"
      },
      "min": 1,
      "max": 5,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_vendor",
      "label": {
        "da": "Vis produktleverandører",
        "de": "Produkt-Lieferanten anzeigen",
        "en": "Show product vendors",
        "es": "Mostrar proveedores del producto",
        "fi": "Näytä tuotteen myyjät",
        "fr": "Afficher les vendeurs",
        "hi": "उत्पाद विक्रेताओं को दिखाएं",
        "it": "Mostra fornitori prodotto",
        "ja": "商品の販売元を表示する",
        "ko": "제품 공급 업체 표시",
        "nb": "Vis produktleverandører",
        "nl": "Productleveranciers weergeven",
        "pt-BR": "Exibir fornecedores do produto",
        "pt-PT": "Mostrar fornecedores do produto",
        "sv": "Visa produktleverantörer",
        "th": "แสดงผู้ขายสินค้า",
        "zh-CN": "显示产品厂商",
        "zh-TW": "顯示產品廠商"
      },
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "label": {
        "da": "Vis knappen \"Se flere\"",
        "de": "'Alle anzeigen' Button anzeigen",
        "en": "Show 'View all' button",
        "es": "Mostrar el botón 'Ver todo'",
        "fi": "Näytä \"Näytä kaikki\" -painike",
        "fr": "Afficher le bouton “Tout voir”",
        "hi": "'सभी देखें' बटन दिखाएं",
        "it": "Mostra il pulsante \"Visualizza tutto\"",
        "ja": "「すべて表示」ボタンを表示する",
        "ko": "'모두 보기' 버튼 표시",
        "nb": "Vis «Se alle»-knapp",
        "nl": "Knop 'Alles weergeven' weergeven",
        "pt-BR": "Exibir botão 'Visualizar tudo'",
        "pt-PT": "Mostrar botão 'Ver tudo'",
        "sv": "Visa \"Visa alla\"-knappen",
        "th": "แสดงปุ่ม 'ดูทั้งหมด'",
        "zh-CN": "显示“查看全部”按钮",
        "zh-TW": "顯示「檢視全部」按鈕"
      },
      "default": false
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": {
        "da": "Udvalgt kollektion",
        "de": "Vorgestellte Kategorie",
        "en": "Category collection",
        "es": "Colección destacada",
        "fi": "Esittelyssä oleva kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection en vedette",
        "hi": "फ़ीचर्ड कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione in evidenza",
        "ja": "特集コレクション",
        "ko": "추천 컬렉션",
        "nb": "Utvalgt samling",
        "nl": "Uitgelichte collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção em destaque",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção em destaque",
        "sv": "Utvald kollektion",
        "th": "คอลเลกชันแนะนำ",
        "zh-CN": "特色产品系列",
        "zh-TW": "精選商品系列"
      },
      "category": {
        "da": "Kollektion",
        "de": "Kategorie",
        "en": "Collection",
        "es": "Colección",
        "fi": "Kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection",
        "hi": "कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione",
        "ja": "コレクション",
        "ko": "컬렉션",
        "nb": "Samling",
        "nl": "Collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção",
        "sv": "Produktserie",
        "th": "คอลเลกชัน",
        "zh-CN": "收藏",
        "zh-TW": "商品系列"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `"side-banner"` div  for banner image & using jQuery give banner height as `ul` same height you can see this image : https://i.ibb.co/9nCgm1G/8c23e547-e7cd-4417-92a6-6b0e454ebe9e.png

```html
{% if section.settings.title != blank %}
    <div class="section-header text-center">
      <h2>{{ section.settings.title | escape }}</h2>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

  {%- assign collection = collections[section.settings.collection] -%}

  {% case section.settings.grid %}
    {% when 2 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 530 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'medium-up--one-half' -%}
    {% when 3 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 345 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-third' -%}
    {% when 4 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 250 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-quarter' -%}
    {% when 5 %}
      {%- assign max_height = 195 -%}
      {%- assign grid_item_width = 'small--one-half medium-up--one-fifth' -%}
  {% endcase %}

  {%- assign product_limit = section.settings.grid | times: section.settings.rows -%}

      <div class="side-banner">
      <div class="image-box"  style="background: url({{section.settings.image_banner | img_url:'master' }});">
      
    </div>
      </div>
  <ul class="grid grid--uniform grid--view-items">
  
        
    {% for product in collection.products limit: product_limit %}
      <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
        {% include 'product-card-grid', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
      </li>
    {% else %}

      {% for i in (1..product_limit) %}
        <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
          <div class="grid-view-item product-card">
            <a class="grid-view-item__link grid-view-item__image-container full-width-link" href="#">
              <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</span>
            </a>
            <div class="grid-view-item__image-wrapper">
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'product-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
            <div class="h4 grid-view-item__title" aria-hidden="true">{{ 'homepage.onboarding.product_title' | t }}</div>
            {% include 'product-price' %}
          </div>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  {% if section.settings.show_view_all %}
    <hr class="hr--invisible" aria-hidden="true" />
    <div class="text-center">
      <a href="{{ collection.url }}" class="btn" aria-label="{{ 'collections.general.view_all_label' | t: collection_name: collection.title }}">
        {{ 'collections.general.view_all' | t }}
      </a>
    </div>
  {% endif %}

</div>

<style>
.side-banner {
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
      margin-right: 25px;
}

ul.grid.grid--uniform.grid--view-items {
    display: inline-block;
}

.side-banner .image-box {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: unset !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
  
</style>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": {
    "da": "Udvalgt kollektion",
    "de": "Vorgestellte Kategorie",
    "en": "Category collection",
    "es": "Colección destacada",
    "fi": "Esittelyssä oleva kokoelma",
    "fr": "Collection en vedette",
    "hi": "फ़ीचर्ड कलेक्शन",
    "it": "Collezione in evidenza",
    "ja": "特集コレクション",
    "ko": "추천 컬렉션",
    "nb": "Utvalgt samling",
    "nl": "Uitgelichte collectie",
    "pt-BR": "Coleção em destaque",
    "pt-PT": "Coleção em destaque",
    "sv": "Utvald kollektion",
    "th": "คอลเลกชันแนะนำ",
    "zh-CN": "特色产品系列",
    "zh-TW": "精選商品系列"
  },
  "class": "index-section",
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": {
        "da": "Overskrift",
        "de": "Titel",
        "en": "Heading",
        "es": "Título",
        "fi": "Otsake",
        "fr": "En-tête",
        "hi": "शीर्षक",
        "it": "Heading",
        "ja": "見出し",
        "ko": "제목",
        "nb": "Overskrift",
        "nl": "Kop",
        "pt-BR": "Título",
        "pt-PT": "Título",
        "sv": "Rubrik",
        "th": "ส่วนหัว",
        "zh-CN": "标题",
        "zh-TW": "標題"
      },
      "default": {
        "da": "Udvalgt kollektion",
        "de": "Vorgestellte Kategorie",
        "en": "Category collection",
        "es": "Colección destacada",
        "fi": "Esittelyssä oleva kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection en vedette",
        "hi": "फ़ीचर्ड कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione in evidenza",
        "ja": "特集コレクション",
        "ko": "추천 컬렉션",
        "nb": "Fremhevet samling",
        "nl": "Uitgelichte collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção em destaque",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção em destaque",
        "sv": "Utvald kollektion",
        "th": "คอลเลกชันแนะนำ",
        "zh-CN": "特色产品系列",
        "zh-TW": "精選商品系列"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "collection",
      "type": "collection",
      "label": {
        "da": "Kollektion",
        "de": "Kategorie",
        "en": "Collection",
        "es": "Colección",
        "fi": "Kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection",
        "hi": "कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione",
        "ja": "コレクション",
        "ko": "컬렉션",
        "nb": "Samling",
        "nl": "Collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção",
        "sv": "Produktserie",
        "th": "คอลเลกชัน",
        "zh-CN": "收藏",
        "zh-TW": "商品系列"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "grid",
      "label": {
        "da": "Produkter pr. række",
        "de": "Produkte per Reihe",
        "en": "Products per row",
        "es": "Productos por fila",
        "fi": "Tuotteita per rivi",
        "fr": "Produits par rangée",
        "hi": "प्रति पंक्ति उत्पाद",
        "it": "Prodotti per riga",
        "ja": "行あたりの商品数",
        "ko": "열 별 제품",
        "nb": "Produkter per rad",
        "nl": "Producten per rij",
        "pt-BR": "Produtos por linha",
        "pt-PT": "Produtos por linha",
        "sv": "Produkter per rad",
        "th": "สินค้าต่อแถว",
        "zh-CN": "每行产品数",
        "zh-TW": "每列產品數"
      },
      "min": 2,
      "max": 5,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "range",
      "id": "rows",
      "label": {
        "da": "Rækker",
        "de": "Reihen",
        "en": "Rows",
        "es": "Filas",
        "fi": "Rivit",
        "fr": "Rangées",
        "hi": "पंक्ति",
        "it": "Righe",
        "ja": "行",
        "ko": "열",
        "nb": "Rader",
        "nl": "Rijen",
        "pt-BR": "Linhas",
        "pt-PT": "Linhas",
        "sv": "Rader",
        "th": "แถว",
        "zh-CN": "行数",
        "zh-TW": "列"
      },
      "min": 1,
      "max": 5,
      "step": 1,
      "default": 2
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_vendor",
      "label": {
        "da": "Vis produktleverandører",
        "de": "Produkt-Lieferanten anzeigen",
        "en": "Show product vendors",
        "es": "Mostrar proveedores del producto",
        "fi": "Näytä tuotteen myyjät",
        "fr": "Afficher les vendeurs",
        "hi": "उत्पाद विक्रेताओं को दिखाएं",
        "it": "Mostra fornitori prodotto",
        "ja": "商品の販売元を表示する",
        "ko": "제품 공급 업체 표시",
        "nb": "Vis produktleverandører",
        "nl": "Productleveranciers weergeven",
        "pt-BR": "Exibir fornecedores do produto",
        "pt-PT": "Mostrar fornecedores do produto",
        "sv": "Visa produktleverantörer",
        "th": "แสดงผู้ขายสินค้า",
        "zh-CN": "显示产品厂商",
        "zh-TW": "顯示產品廠商"
      },
      "default": false
    },
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_view_all",
      "label": {
        "da": "Vis knappen \"Se flere\"",
        "de": "'Alle anzeigen' Button anzeigen",
        "en": "Show 'View all' button",
        "es": "Mostrar el botón 'Ver todo'",
        "fi": "Näytä \"Näytä kaikki\" -painike",
        "fr": "Afficher le bouton “Tout voir”",
        "hi": "'सभी देखें' बटन दिखाएं",
        "it": "Mostra il pulsante \"Visualizza tutto\"",
        "ja": "「すべて表示」ボタンを表示する",
        "ko": "'모두 보기' 버튼 표시",
        "nb": "Vis «Se alle»-knapp",
        "nl": "Knop 'Alles weergeven' weergeven",
        "pt-BR": "Exibir botão 'Visualizar tudo'",
        "pt-PT": "Mostrar botão 'Ver tudo'",
        "sv": "Visa \"Visa alla\"-knappen",
        "th": "แสดงปุ่ม 'ดูทั้งหมด'",
        "zh-CN": "显示“查看全部”按钮",
        "zh-TW": "顯示「檢視全部」按鈕"
      },
      "default": false
    },

        {
          "id": "image_banner",
          "type": "image_picker",
          "label": "Image"
       
    
        }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": {
        "da": "Udvalgt kollektion",
        "de": "Vorgestellte Kategorie",
        "en": "Category collection",
        "es": "Colección destacada",
        "fi": "Esittelyssä oleva kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection en vedette",
        "hi": "फ़ीचर्ड कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione in evidenza",
        "ja": "特集コレクション",
        "ko": "추천 컬렉션",
        "nb": "Utvalgt samling",
        "nl": "Uitgelichte collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção em destaque",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção em destaque",
        "sv": "Utvald kollektion",
        "th": "คอลเลกชันแนะนำ",
        "zh-CN": "特色产品系列",
        "zh-TW": "精選商品系列"
      },
      "category": {
        "da": "Kollektion",
        "de": "Kategorie",
        "en": "Collection",
        "es": "Colección",
        "fi": "Kokoelma",
        "fr": "Collection",
        "hi": "कलेक्शन",
        "it": "Collezione",
        "ja": "コレクション",
        "ko": "컬렉션",
        "nb": "Samling",
        "nl": "Collectie",
        "pt-BR": "Coleção",
        "pt-PT": "Coleção",
        "sv": "Produktserie",
        "th": "คอลเลกชัน",
        "zh-CN": "收藏",
        "zh-TW": "商品系列"
      }
    }
    
    
  ]
}
{% endschema %}




<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var currentHeight = 0;
    $(window).load(function() {

        banner_height();

    });
    document.addEventListener("shopify:section:load", function(event) {
       banner_height();
    });
});

function banner_height(){
    currentHeight = $('ul.grid.grid--uniform.grid--view-items').outerHeight();
    console.log("set current height on load = " + currentHeight)
    $('.side-banner').css('height', currentHeight);

}

</script>
```